# How to implement INotifyCollectionChanged (Add action after added collection of items to source)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I created my own source which implemented inotifycollectionchanged interface ... I need raise collectionchanged after addrange, more items is added to source (not when one item is added) WinRT. I have this

```
     public class MySource2 : IList, INotifyCollectionChanged
   {
      private List<object> items = new List<object>(); 
      public MySource2(IEnumerable<object> initialDataSet)
      {
         items.AddRange(initialDataSet);
      }

      public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
      {
         return items.GetEnumerator();
      }

      public void AddItems(IEnumerable<object> additionalItems)
      {
         int oldCount = Count;
         items.AddRange(additionalItems);
         this.RaiseItemsAdded(oldCount, additionalItems.ToList());
      }

      public object this[int index]
      {
         get
         {
            return items[index];
         }
         set
         {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
         }
      }

      public int Count
      {
         get
         {
            return items.Count;
         }
      }

      public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

      private void RaiseItemsAdded(int index, IList newItems)
      {
         var handlers = this.CollectionChanged;

         if (handlers != null)
         {
            var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newItems, index);

            handlers(this, args);
         }
      }
```

This throw Argument exception (parameter is incorect) ... What am I doing wrong?
          }

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: I believe you should call RaiseItemsAdded like this:
this.RaiseItemsAdded(oldCount - 1, additionalItems.ToList());

Comment: is unhandled exception (I have turned on CLR exceptions) .. @Nick did not help

Comment: Make sure the `index` being passed in is correct. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms653208), you'll get an `ArgumentException` on `Add` when `index` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Not to tell you how to code your app, but have you considered a simpler approach?

```
public class MyList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.AddRange(items);
        var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, items.ToList(), null);
        base.OnCollectionChanged(args);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    { RemoveRange(this.Where(predicate)); }

    private void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.RemoveRange(items);
        var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, null, items.ToList());
        base.OnCollectionChanged(args);
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Observable collection doesn't have AddRange ... When I call AddRange in your implementation the result is infinite loop ??